# Template rendering .svg file from public directory

Tags: html, meteor, svg

This Meteor template failed to render the `public/calender.svg` file but instead it renders a standard placeholder image.
How can I get it to show the content of the calender.svg file? Thanks

```
<img src="/{{image}}.svg"/>
```

[image]

The content of the file is:

```
'<svg height="24px" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24px"><g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" id="miu" stroke="none" stroke-width="1"><g id="Artboard-1" transform="translate(-792.000000, -335.000000)"><g id="slice" transform="translate(215.000000, 119.000000)"/><path d="M805.920365,339 ... " fill="#000000"/></g></g></svg>'
```

**edit**
If I change the file to .png then it works.

Comment: Does it render the calendar.svg image if you hard code it there? Instead of the spacebars.

Comment: The Template is rendering before the helper is called, so when the template is initially rendered, it can't find the image. I'm not sure how to fix that because I have never done it. This SO post might help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26997361/meteor-js-calling-a-template-helper-within-template-rendered

Comment: @TIC if I change the file to `image.png` then it works.

Comment: does the file indeed start with `'<svg`, i.e., including the quotation marks? If so, then that's not valid svg.

Comment: @ChristianFritz I fixed something in the format as you hinted and it works now. thx